# Is there an organised list of all SWT widgets and styles with explanation?

Tags: java, eclipse, widget, swt

I'm learning to use SWT, but the variety is bewildering and the information is sketchy.

I've encountered [a long list of widget classes and styles](https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT_Widget_Style_Bits) without explanation what each of them is. The links on the page are dead. I've tried to search for individual ones but didn't find much about some of them. `Widget` is obviously an abstract class on the bottom, so it can refer to any widget. `Control` is also an abstract class, which most widgets extend, but the only thing I managed to find about it was from its source code, that's how I know it's abstract.

What I was looking for was am organised list which shows the hierarchy of all widget classes, which ones are abstract and briefly what each of them is for, and the list of styles with brielf information which widget classes they affect and how...

Comment: I fixed the links on the mentioned wiki page. I prefer the [SWT snippets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) and looking into the Javadoc instead (not only because both are always up to date).

Comment: The "Platform Plug-in Developer Guide" part of the Eclipse Help included in the Eclipse download (for the plug-in development versions) has lots about SWT.

Answer (score 1):

[SWT Widgets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/) would be  avery good starting point. This lists different widgets with screenshots(these are taken on Mac) and associated javadoc

Answer (score 0):

After I've typed pretty much all of the question I found this elusive site, to which I believe the dead links should be pointing: [Help - Eclipse Platform](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/package-summary.html).

It doesn't exactly show the hierarchy, but it lists widgets, what they are for, which ones are abstract.

It lists all SWT constants, first briefly, then grouped with more explanation on each; one of the groups is styles.

Plus there's a lot more, organised into packages. Not just SWT, other Eclipse packages, too.